# Parse query retrieve pointer columns

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I have a Filter class which has a pointer to a user in my User class. I'm wondering how can I get the Filter object in the Filter class which is equal to the `[PFUser CurrentUser]` and then get both column values from the User and Filter class

```
PFQuery *filterQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Filter"];
filterQuery.limit = 1;
[filterQuery whereKey:@"userId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
[filterQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
     if(!error){                                
         NSLog(@"%@", objects);                                                                                                         
     }                                                     
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the object itself...

```
PFQuery *filterQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Filter"];
filterQuery.limit = 1;
[filterQuery whereKey:@"userId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]]; //no need to put objected here.
[filterQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
     if(!error){                                
         NSLog(@"%@", objects);                                                                                                         
     }                                                     
}];
```

As long as the `userId` field is a pointer to the `_User` object then this will work.

If `userId` is a pointer to `_User` then you can add...

```
[filterQuery includeKey:@"userId"];
```

This will then populate the `userId` object of the `Filter` objects with data when they are sent down. If you don't put that line then you will just get the `objectId` in the `userId` object.

However, I'm not sure you've done it as a Pointer. Can you confirm that it definitely is.

You should have this in the Data Browser table for Filter...

[image]

(follower will say userId on yours)

Comment: don't i need to include keys?

Comment: i can confirm that in my Filter class their is a column which is a pointer to _User. But how do i retrieve the data from the User column i've added your code.

Comment: @FrederikHagelund you logged objects. You should be able to see from there... Something like this... `objects[0][@"userId"][@"userName"];`